# Regular Expression for any HTML Tag with a specific attribute

Tags: html, regex, tags

I'm looking for a regular expression that checks for any html tag (assume any string of a-z longer than 1 letter is valid), with any number of attributes so long as one of which is an action="POST".

i.e the following would match:
`<a href="www.somelink.com" action="POST" />
 <img action="POST" src="www.someimage.com" ></img>`

**BUT** this would not
`<a href="www.somelink.com" />`

I have been working on this and came to the below,

`^<([a-z]+)([^<]*)*action="POST"(?:>(.*)<\/\1>|\s+\/>)$`

however it is not matching (and crashing some reg ex checkers). Any thoughts or pushes in the right direction?
`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @sputnick That's mostly unrelated, though still carries a good message.

Comment: It's related: don't parse HTML with REGEX !

Comment: I know its a big no no, I'm not actually using it in a project, its more to prove a concept to a question posed by a friend... that I'm admittedly having difficulty with! :) thanks everyone!

Comment: 1.) Remove [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) 2.) `([^<]*)*` [see here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html) 3.) [example with lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/sV5yM6/1) (see explanation top right). It's not recommended to parse html with regex, especially if nested.

Comment: downvoting... mature "doesn't show research effort unclear or unuseful", for a place thats meant to be accessible and help people it can be unfriendly. Unnecessary downvote with no explanation or ownership to it. I have provided examples of what I have tried and even further explained in my comments as to why I required this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//*[@action="POST"]' file_or_URL
```